# Entity Framework 6 - get deferred IQueryable from navigation collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I have a simple entity with following relation:

```
class Foo 
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar { get; set; }
    public boolean Active { get; set; }
    public boolean Condition{ get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

In code I use this navigation collection with a dynamic query and have the problem that the loading is not deferred until the iteration.

```
public void doSomething(Bar bar, bool condition)
{
    // even with lazy loading all Foo's have been loaded here
    IQueryable<Foo> foos = bar.Foos.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.Active);

    if (condition)
        foos = foos.Where(f => f.Condition);

    // I want to defer loading until all filters are applied
    foreach (Foo foo in foos)
    {
        // do something with foo
    }
}
```

How do I defer the loading, without using explicit queries using my `Bar` repository and manually doing a Select with those conditions like:

```
IRepository<Foo> repoFoo = uow.getRepository<Foo>();
IQueryable<Foo> queryFoo = repoBar.getQuery().Where(f => f.BarID = bar.ID && bar.Active)

// check condition
```

Comment: Wouldn't the deferred execution take place until you execute the foreach loop? Before that, i do not see your code iterating over the result set.

Comment: How do you know that foo items have been loaded in the first line of doSomething?

Comment: @Agalo No, it will be lazy loaded when accessed by `bar.Foos`

Comment: I see it when i debug the SQL log

Comment: The short answer is - you can't do that. You need access to either `context.Bars` or `context.Foos` (the later is preferable)

Comment: @IvanStoev Seems you are right. so I must disable lazy loading and use this construct https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx. This sucks a lot.  They must load it when certain methods of the collection are called and not the collections itself via a getter. Maybe thats why the stripped lazy-loading from EF7, cause of this missconception.